# How to check which Gridview is selected, if form having more than one Gridview?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

In form i created **three dynamic Gridview** ,  I want to perform some specific operations on selection of particular Gridview, can any one help me how to know which gridview got seletec?

Answer (score 0):

There is a .GotFocus() event on the DataGridView you can use to store something in a form scope (or global) variable. (sorry for the VB...)

```
Dim LastGirdWithFocus As String = ""

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    MsgBox(LastGirdWithFocus)
End Sub

Private Sub dgv1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles dgv1.GotFocus, dgv2.GotFocus
    LastGirdWithFocus = sender.name
End Sub
```